# SPD Approval Workflow runs slow in the morning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint Designer (SPD) Approval workflow running in SP2010 mode. It works fine but the first person who tries Approving/Rejecting the workflow in the morning has to wait 30-40 seconds for the Approval/rejection task to complete, it just spins for that duration.

The workflow status also takes a few refreshes to update, causing confusion if it successfully updated. The next approval takes less time and after that it completes in 2-3 seconds.

I understand the workflow engine needs to be warmed up but I couldn't find a way to warmup it up. Is there a script that someone can provide to warm up the Workflow engine please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To warm up the workflow engine, we can create a simple workflow and run it on the list item.

There is an article below to discuss the issue, but it does not provide the script to warm up workflow engine.

SharePoint Workflow and Warmup Scripts.

http://celerity12.blogspot.sg/2010/03/sharepoint-workflow-and-warmup-scripts.html

To improve the workflow performance, we can increase throttle size, increase default batch size, increase time out and increase workflow timer interval by PowerShell script.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

Increase SharePoint Workflow performance and reliability.

http://www.sharepointfire.com/2015/04/increase-sharepoint-workflow-performance-and-reliability/

Improving Workflow Performance – SharePoint 2013.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33936.improving-workflow-performance-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Thanks Amy, I've scheduled basic WF to run every morning. When tested it wasn't a full-proof solution as the Workflow service is started on four servers. The work around I could think of was to make the warmup WF run several times in the morning hours hoping it wakes up WF timer jobs on all the servers where WF service is running. 

I'm still testing this, will confirm in a few days.

Comment: update - I scheduled the problem WF to run 4-5 times between 6-7AM everyday and there was no improvement. 

Based on my tests, it warms up only when I run the warmup WF manually. When it is scheduled using Nintex WF scheduler or PowerShell, the subsequent WFs are still slow.

Comment: I suggest you could consider improving the workflow performance according to the articles in my previous post.

Comment: Hi Amy, the SharePoint farm is not overloaded with a lot of workflows. And the ones that we have are not very complex. So I wonder if increasing the throttle, batch size will help. I will still give that a shot and get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We opened a case with Microsoft and they confirmed that this cannot be fixed for SP2010 WFs. You must recreate the WFs either in Workflow Manager (separate server) or use Visual studio based pre-compiled workflows.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3043697/a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-in-sharepoint-online-takes-longer-than-expe